Encourage Elm to use optimized batch DOM manipulation method
I've got a view with thousands of items to display. How do I encourage Elm to utilize something more optimized for list of items like document fragment rather than appendChild?


Have you tried using Html.Keyed? This allows you to provide a String key for each item in the list, which is then used by the diffing algorithm to apply changes to the correct child.
You may also want to investigate elm-optimize-level-2, though I don't immediately see that it has any specific optimizations around appendChild.

I did try Html.Keyed.node it didn't help at all ‍♂️
